# How add root container to NextJS?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I would set a React portal, hence add a modal container in the root HTML as following:

```
<div id="app-root"></div>
<div id="modal-root"></div> // new container added
```

How do that in NextJS please?

thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do that in a `_document.js` under the `pages` folder:

```
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
 render() {
    return (
      <html>
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
          <div id="modal-root" />
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
}
```